# How to utilize :visited on parent elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

I basically have a listing of content, which all goes to external url's (it opens them in new windows). As of right now, i have a:visited set to gray, although what i would REALLY love is for the whole list item (which contains the anchor link they click on) to have a reduced opacity.

You can see this behavior on reddit.

Say for example you have

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="http://google.com">Click me</a>
</div>
```

And then you have many rows of `.item`

I want it so that when you click on the link, the entire div can 'see' the :visited state, and so `.item` gets set to `opacity: .5;`, as opposed to just the text turning gray.

Is there a way to do this with JS or css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there isn't a `:visited` selector in jQuery. Check out this plugin for including it:
http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/

Using this plugin, you can implement this effect using either this:

```
$("a").visited().each(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("opacity", "0.5");
});
```

or this:

```
$(".item").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("a").visited().length;
}).css("opacity", "0.5");
```

Comment: I tried this before, but when i do `$('a:visited')` right in console (when there are blatantly clicked links on the screen), i just get an empty array of `[]`. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Tallboy - My bad, I wasn't aware that jQuery didn't have a `visited` selector. Look at the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any downside that you know of to have iframes on my site? For SEO or any other reasons?

Comment: @Tallboy - Not that I'm aware of, but you should be warned I'm never very knowledge in dealing with `iframe`s.

Comment: `:visited` selector isn't allowed for privacy reasons in JavaScript.

Comment: Oh dear, I'd forgotten -- @alex is quite [right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

Comment: @Tallboy - I've never actually used it, but I'm pretty sure it works. I found numerous links to it and people wouldn't bother publishing a nonworking plugin...

Comment: @jeff It may have worked in 2008, but not anymore -- all the browsers clamped down on this after a bit of Spyjax popularity in 2010.

Comment: yeah it doesnt work. Due to the lack of an 'answer' for this post though I just marked it as an answer.. unless someone has some kind of idea to do this with cookies i guess im screwed

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly a solution to your technical problem, but would it be possible to alter your structure to make the `<a>` accomplish the stylistic needs of the `<div>` parent?

In other words, kill the `<div>`, and just use the `<a>`. That way, when it's "visited," you can do whatever you want right to it.

Comment: I wish this were the case, but unfortunately it's too far into my app, and also the .item has way too many things inside it besides a link for me to effectively wrap the whole thing in an anchor

Comment: Do you think i could use a hack, maybe like `a:visited div.hack` and assign that a special value like `display:none; border-color: blue`, and then select any element with a border color of 'blue', and take its parent?

Comment: I think you actually have a few options, depending on how "hacky" you want to get. The easiest would be the plugin that's been mentioned. Without going into code specifics, you could also store to and read from some type of local storage (JS api/cookies). As in, when someone clicks a link, store an identifier in the local storage/cookie, then when your page loads, add a "visited" class to that link.  Simultaneously, when the user clicks the link, insta-add the "visited" class. Your div.hack should work if done right, too. Just the issue of browser support with the ":visited rule" selector.

Answer (score 0):

Once [CSS4 selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) are supported (assuming the present draft is accepted in something similar to its current form),

```
div.item! > a:visited
```

will select the parent `div` with class `item` of a visited `a`.

Until then, [cssParentSelector](https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector) may work.